# Escape single apostrophe when using SELECT from SQL, into an array in C# then UPDATE

Tags: c#, .net, sql, t-sql

In my C# code I read in all id's of a table into a string array `ids[i]`, then update a different column in the table WHERE user_id = id[i].

The problem occurs when the id being read(also passed back into the `UPDATE`) contains an apostrophe - '

```
       while (rdr.Read()
       {
          ids[i] = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim();
          ids[i].Replace("'", "''");
          ....
```

I have also tried `ids[i].Replace("'", "\'");`
and `ids[i].Replace("'", "-");` but I'm sure this will throw off my WHERE as it will look for user_id "O-Test" as opposed to "O'Test".

My UPDATE SQL is along the lines of:

```
 UPDATE [User]
 SET first_name = '{1}'
 WHERE [user_id] = '{2}'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Use parameters instead of string literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to assign it back to `ids[i]`

```
ids[i] = ids[i].Replace("'", "''");
```

`ids[i].Replace("'", "''");` this will only create a string in memory and discard it, you need to assign it back to `ids[i]` in your while loop.

So your code should be:

```
while (rdr.Read()
       {
          ids[i] = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim();
          ids[i] = ids[i].Replace("'", "''");
          ....
```